# Web Page for Siemens S71200 - Refresh only the values

Tags: html

i am new in html programming and i need your help.

I had write a html page for remore control of S71200, but i need to refresh my div values without refresh all page.

I will write all the html page. Can you help me?

```
<div id="text5" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:221px; top:158px;width:49px; height:24px; z-index:13">
<div class="wpmd">
<div><font color="#808080" face="Tahoma">:="My_Variable":</font></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: "here's some giftwrap. you go buy the present". No, we can't help you. you haven't explained what these "div values" are, where or how you retrieve them, or how you want them displayed.

Comment: please first explain what kind of device this "Siemens S71200" is, is it a server? printer? electric BBQ grill?. what technologies does it use? php? asp? where does this `:="My_Variable":` come from? how much free space you have on this device for storing your code? have you tried accomplishing it with AJAX? what have you tried so far anyway?

Comment: You cannot do that with Pure HTML.

Comment: S71200 is a PLC that support web server and i want to fix a html page to see remotely some variables. :="My_Variable": is one from them. I want to refresh the value of this variable without to refresh all page, because i have locked this page with password and with refresh asked again the pasword.

Answer (score -1):

**Use JQuery**
You can use JQuery for that.
Using JQuery's `html()`-function.
Check my codesnippet at http://jsfiddle.net/6L7n5t41/2/

You can add Jquery for your html-site using script-tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
```